# Escape user input for Regex parsing

Tags: php, regex, validation, escaping

I have a website where users can search text files from an input form. The website posts the search to the server where it does a `shell_exec grep -E "^(LOG|DATE)+.$query"` type command.

The log file contains special characters like `[( and if the user wants to should be able to search for them.

The problem is that certain characters "break" the grep function. Is there a list of characters that I need to escape before processing the data or a built in function? `escapeshellarg` doesn't work in this case and I couldn't find a list online of characters that should be escaped

Comment: Why are you using `shell_exec`? Use PHP's built-in `preg_match`, and use `preg_quote` to escape the input.

Comment: The files are huge and PHP is magnitutes slower than grep

Comment: You could try using `preg_quote` before calling `escapeshellarg`. But since PHP's regexp is not the same as grep's, there might be some incompatibilities.

Comment: @Barmar Yes your solution worked. The function I was looking for was preg_quote. Post as answer so I can +rep and accept. Thanks!

Comment: There's already an answer that recommends preg_quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using PHP, use [`preg_match('/patern/', $str);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).
To escape string for regex, use [`preg_quote($str)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

Comment: `preg_match` doesn't have a `replacement` argument, that's `preg_replace`.